# Get only replies on a certain language in Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using the graph API to search result about a subjet on a multilingue web site.
For example : Sarkozy.

So, i use this url : https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Sarkozy.

Then, i want to have replies only in a certain language or country, for example English, Spainish, French.

Does someone know what is the request url to obtain this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Add `&locale=en_US` as a parameter for example to get only US English results.  You may also try setting the Accept-Language http header.

Answer (score 2):

The above mentioned `&locale=en_US` kind of parameter does not filter the search results any more ([since early December 2012](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/294623187324442)).

Originally listed as a bug this behaviour (not filtering by language) has now been declared to work as intended(!).

Unfortunately I’m not familiar with any workaround or other solution.

Comment: Seems that they fixed it by now!

Comment: They fixed it in April but then it broke again at the beginning of May. Right now https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Sarkozy&locale=fr_FR gives results gives results in English, French, Croatian, Greek etc. (and https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Sarkozy&locale=en_US gives similar results in mixed languages).

Answer (score -1):

You can use Accept-Language header.

C# example

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
    result = client.DownloadString(searchUrl);
}
```